# libGDX stage draw me mirrored text

Tags: libgdx

I use `Stage` in `libGDX` for drawing GUI and adding listeners to controls in my game.

But when I draw text on  ImageTextButton I get mirrored text as displayed on image below.

Can some help me and tell me how to draw normal text, not mirrored ?

```
            stage = new Stage(Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_WIDTH, Constants.VIEWPORT_GUI_HEIGHT);
            stage.clear();
    ....

            ImageTextButtonStyle  imageTextButtonStyle = new ImageTextButtonStyle();
            imageTextButtonStyle.font = Assets.instance.fonts.defaultSmall;

            ImageTextButton imageTextButton = new ImageTextButton("ddsds", imageTextButtonStyle);
            imageTextButton.setBackground( gameUISkin.getDrawable("fil_coins"));
            imageTextButton.setPosition(50, 600);
            imageTextButton.setHeight(85);
            imageTextButton.setWidth(183);

           stage.addActor(imageTextButton);

....
    public void render (float deltaTime) {

        stage.act(deltaTime);
        stage.draw();
    }
```

[image: mirrored text]

Thanks

Edit:
Button images are shown correct, only text has mirrored view

Comment: I think it should be something with your camera/ the projection matrix of your SpriteBatch. Can you post the code where you set the cam and the matrix?

Comment: @Springrbua I think Stage has own camera  and sprite batch

Comment: Yea i know. I just thought you may manipulated them someway.
Try: For your BitMapFont `boolean isFlipped()`
"Returns true if this BitmapFont has been flipped for use with a y-down coordinate system. "

Comment: thanks @Springrbua font was flipped for y-down use. I can't accept this as answer it is in comment

Comment: Good that i could help (: Did not think that this is the solution xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Springrbua suggest me in comment below, my bitmap font was flipped when creating.

```
defaultSmall = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("images/font.fnt"), true);
```

should be

```
defaultSmall = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("images/font.fnt"), false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Even it's not case here it may be useful for someone - if font size parameter is set to negative value, text will be rendered upside-down (Y-scale).

Comment: Thank you! My font scale was set with a negative Y ie. `whiteFont.setScale(.25f, -.25f);`. Changing it to a positive fixed it.